# How to reset redux form in popup?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reset, react-redux-form

I have a button "addData" , which opens modal with form inside, and a grid, on which click of row opens same model (with pre-filled valus).

My problem is, after clicking on row, when i click on "addData" button the form should be reset, but it is having previous pre-filled value.

Note that i am initializing form values with props. Whereas "addData" button is in another component(does it make any difference? because my other functionalities working totally fine).

```
this.props.initialize({ title: data[0].title, startdate: data[0]})
```

Below code is not working for me,

```
$(document).on("click", "#addData", function (e) {
   // dispatch(reset("myformName"));
   dispatch(initialize('myformName', {}));
});
```

It is throwing error "dispatch is not defined". What i did wrong?

How can i reset redux form in model? Can't i reset on click event of button?

Answer (score 0):

You're using dispatch as a standalone function. `dispatch` is a method of redux's store.
You'll need to either `import` the store and use

`store.dispatch(initialize('myformName', {}));`

or better - use `mapDispatchToProps` and attach the `action` to the `addData` click.
Using jquery with react-redux is a really bad practice and this is one of the examples why. If you have trouble connecting `mapDisatchToProps` with your component post your component code.